# Send email if woocommerce order has items from a specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, email-notifications

I am having some problems with the code below, i am looking to send an email when an order completes on woo commerce, that catch is that it must be of a certain category can someone please help.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_catmail', 'my_function' );

    function my_function($order_id) {
       $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

       foreach($order->get_items() as $orderid) {
          if ($orderid['product_cat']== 630) {
             $_product = get_product($item['product_id']);
             $to_email = $order->billing_email;
             $headers = 'From: Your Name <your@email.com>' . "\r\n";
             wp_mail($to_email, 'subject', 'message', $headers );
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will send a custom email to customer for a specific product category when order status is changed to "completed":

```
// On order completed status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'send_a_custom_email', 20, 1 );
function send_a_custom_email( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product(); // The WC_Product object

        // Get the parent product ID for product variations for product categories
        $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

        if (  has_term( array( 630 ), 'product_cat', $the_id ) ) {
            $to_email = $order->get_billing_email(); // To customer
            $subject = "Your subject goes here";
            $message = "Your message goes here";
            $headers = 'From: Shop Name <shop@email.com>' . "\r\n"; // From admin email

            wp_mail( $to_email, $subject, $message, $headers ); // Send email
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works

Comment: thanks for your reply, can i email to a specific email address

$to_email = "email@email.com";